# Batch rename photos by creation date on Mac OS X using Bash not working with spaces

Tags: bash, mac

I've been searching for a solution on how to batch rename photos on Mac OS X. I've found many solutions but most of them don't work if the file has either a space in it or if I want to put a space in the filename.

For example I found this script:

`for i in *.jpg; do newname=$(stat -t %Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S -f %Sm -- $i); mv -- $i $newname.jpg; done`

The script works as long as I don't put a space in the final filename (I do want a space in the filename because I've been renaming my files with spaces for the past 3 years on Windows). And it also breaks if the file itself has a space in it. So if I have a photo called "Hello World.jpg", it won't be processed.

Would anyone have a solution for it, please? That preferably doesn't require any additional software (I just want to be able to copy/paste that script each time I switch machines).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use quotes in your substitutions:

```
for i in *.jpg; do newname="$(stat -t %Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S -f %Sm -- "$i")"; mv -- "$i" "$newname.jpg"; done
```

It needs to be double-quotes to allow variable and `$()` expansion.

Comment: For some reason this deletes any file that has a space in it. Not really sure why.

Comment: If you add `echo` in front of `mv`, you can see what the commands will be.

Comment: You need quote marks around `$i` in `$(... $i)`. (This does work, despite the outer quotes.) You should generally put double quotes around *any* variable substitution, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Yes, you're right: I wrongly assumed that the outer quotes covered both. I've updated my answer. Mea Culpa.

Comment: @xtrimsky - I've updated my answer with an extra set of quotes, in response to @jphaugh's comment. Sorry about the omission previously - I was testing on Linux, but the `stat` options seem to be different and I missed the inner quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be enough to replace `$i` by `"$i"`.

Comment: That's more of a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  It's the 5th definition of the adjective : https://www.thefreedictionary.com/normally

Comment: Fair enough. Downvote revoked.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  Respect, you can take a joke!